# Filtering data based on multiple variables

Tags: r, date, if-statement, group-by

I am trying to create a new column based other column criteria where my data looks like the following:

```
ID   Column 1    Column 2    Column 3 
 1     2            Y       "2013-10-22T10:09"
 1     2            Y       "2013-10-23T10:09" 
 2     3            N       "2013-10-23T10:09"
 3     0            Y       "2013-10-23T10:09"
```

For each ID, I would like to keep only the earliest date/time as long as column 1 is greater than 0 and column 2 is not N. The results would look like this:

```
 ID   Column 1    Column 2    Column 3             Column 4
  1     2            Y       "2013-10-22T10:09"    2013-10-22
```

I currently tried this but I was wondering how to do it and if there is an elegant way of doing it:

```
library(dplyr)
ifelse(Column 1 >0 and Column 2 !="N",  
(new %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
arrange(Column 3) %>%
slice(1L)))
Column 4 <- as.Date(Column 3, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
```

Comment: Do you also want to filter the data, i.e., keep only that one line in your example?

Comment: Yes I would also like to filter and keep that one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(Column1 > 0 & Column2 != 'N') %>% # filter out non-matching rows
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  top_n(-1, Column3) %>% # select only the row with the earliest date-time
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Column3)) # create date column

# 
# # A tibble: 1 x 5
# # Groups:   ID [1]
#      ID Column1 Column2 Column3          Date      
#   <int>   <int> <chr>   <chr>            <date>    
# 1     1       2 Y       2013-10-22T10:09 2013-10-22
```

Comment: Or filter first and use distinct()

Comment: Yeah I guess it does make sense to filter first. `Column1` or `Column3` might have many values though, so `distinct` might not be equivalent to selecting the first row / row with earliest date-time.

Comment: Hm, good to know. I assumed distinct(DF, ID, .keep_all = TRUE) worked the same as unique.data.frame(DF, DF$ID) (which always keeps the first row per ID), but I see the docs don't say it and there's no fromLast= argument, so maybe it can't be relied on. Oh, or maybe you're just saying Column3 isn't sorted...

Comment: Oh, I just didn't realize you could use distinct that way, I had always just seen it used with no other arguments `. %>% distinct()` , so good to know. If I did that I'd have to `arrange` first though, so I'll just leave it how it is.

Comment: QQ: If I wanted to keep all the columns and just have the dates blank, is there something I use instead of filter?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `filter` doesn't affect which columns are selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
    rm(list = ls())
    df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,3),column_1 = c(2,2,3,0),
          column_2 = c("Y","Y","N","Y"), 
          column_3 = as.Date(c("2013-10-22","2013-10-23","2013-10-23","2013-10-23"),format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
n <- unique(df$id)
datalist <- list()
for(i in 1:n)
{
  z <- df[df$id == i & df$column_1 > 0 & df$column_2 != "N" & df$column_3 == min(df$column_3),]
  datalist[[i]] <- z
}
do.call(rbind,datalist)
```

This function will help you.
But the constraints for each column were made constant.
You can change it as per your convenience.

Thanks